# The specified conversion is not valid

Tags: c#, oracle

```
using (OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand(cmd, con))
{
    cmd2.BindByName = true;
            
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(":TextBox2", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = TextBox2.Text;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(":TextBox3", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = TextBox3.Text;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(":TextBox4", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = TextBox4.Text;
    cmd2.Parameters.Add(":Label2", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = Label2.Text;

    con.Open();

    dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
}

dt1.Load(dr);

if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Fillrate.DataSource = dt1;
    Fillrate.DataBind();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have three textboxes in which I enter the years, the initial month and the final month. but when loading my data it tells me that there is an invalid conversion.

```
cmd = "select distinct mes as MES, avg(coalesce(Fill_Rate, 0)) as Promedio " +
      " from " +
      "     (select distinct  mes, anno, sum(monto_solicitado) as monto_solic," +
      " sum(Monto_liq) as Monto_liq, case when  sum(nvl(Monto_liq, 0)) <> 0 and sum(nvl(monto_solicitado, 0)) <> 0 then round(sum(nvl(Monto_liq, 0)) / sum(nvl(monto_solicitado, 0)), 2)" +
     " else 0 end as Fill_Rate" +
     " from " +
     " ( select   to_char(m.fecha_emision, 'mm') as mes, to_char(m.fecha_emision, 'yyyy') as anno, c.estado_orden, trunc(c.fecha_emision_orden) as fecha_orden," +
     "m.fecha_emision as fecha_liquidacion, c.moneda, c.numero_orden as orden, mp.no_prove, mp.nombre, oc.cantidad as cant_ordenadas, d.cantidad as cant_liq, (oc.cantidad * oc.precio_unitario)" +
     " as monto_solicitado,(d.costo_unitario * d.cantidad) as Monto_liq " +
     " from com_orden_compra c " +
     " inner join com_detalle_orden_compra oc on oc.numero_orden = c.numero_orden" +
     " inner join com_manifiesto m on m.numero_orden = c.numero_orden" +
     " inner join com_detalle_manifiesto d on d.numero_manifiesto = m.numero_manifiesto and d.codigo_articulo = oc.codigo_articulo" +
     " left join com_gastos_manifiesto g on g.numero_manifiesto = m.numero_manifiesto" +
     " left join arcpmp mp on mp.no_prove = c.identificacion_proveedor" +
     " where m.estatus in ('C', 'A') and c.estado_orden in ('APL', 'TRA', 'CER')" +
     " ) WHERE anno =:TextBox2 and mes between :TextBox3 and :TextBox4 and NO_PROVE=:Label2 " +
     " group by orden, NO_PROVE, nombre, mes, anno, estado_orden, fecha_orden, fecha_liquidacion, moneda, cant_ordenadas, cant_liq" +
     " )tmp" +
     " group by MES" +
     " order by mes";`
```

Comment: You are passing 4 parameters of type varchar2. Now the question is: Are those parameters of the correct type when you use them in the query against the field values? If not then a conversion is required and here there are many paths to get the conversion wrong. Pass parameters of the correct datatype expected by the fields

Comment: The 4 parameters are of type string when I do my query in toad the parameters that I pass are of type string but it still asks me for conversion

Comment: What are the types for the fields _anno_ _mes_ and _NO_PROVE_?

Comment: no_ prove is varchar2 but year and month are of type date so I convert to tochar because in my query it refers to an emission date that is of type date

Comment: Stack Trace / Yellow Page Error would be helpful to anyone.

Comment: Also I suggest you to remove that image because is unreadable and post the query as text. I haven't see this conversion tochar in the where clause.

Comment: modify in such a way see my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

According to [OracleCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8)

> When using named parameters in an SQL statement called by an
> OracleCommand of CommandType.Text, you must precede the parameter name
> with a colon (:). However, in a stored procedure, or when referring to
> a named parameter elsewhere in your code (for example, when adding
> OracleParameter objects to the Parameters property), do not precede
> the named parameter with a colon (:). The .NET Framework Data Provider
> for Oracle supplies the colon automatically.

You'll need to rename the parameters used in the SQL query since `TextBox2.Text` seems to indicate that `TextBox2` is a TextBox control. The same applies to the other parameters.

So instead of using `:TextBox2` in the SQL statement, rename it to something else (ex: `:tb2`). Also put a space between the `=` and the parameter name. Instead of `=:tb2`, do `= :tb2`.

Then in the `Parameters.Add` statement, do the following:

```
 cmd2.Parameters.Add("tb2", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = TextBox2.Text;
```

Notice that `:` isn't used in `Parameters.Add` statement.